# convert morse code to english in c

Tags: c, pointers, loops, malloc, morse-code

I have already done some code but it does not run correctly

what I have done so far

```
void keyread1(void)
{
    char *string1= (char*) malloc (20);//char pointer pointing to allocated memory
    char *string2= (char*) malloc (20);
    char *string3= (char*) malloc (20);
    char *string4= (char*) malloc (20);
    string4[0]='\0';
    printf("Enter word to convert to morse code: \n");
    scanf("%s", string1);
    while (string1!='\0')
    {
        int z=0,a=0;
        strncpy(string2+a, string1+z,4 );
        string3=morse2english(string2);
        strncat(string4+a,string3,1);
        z=z+4;
    }
    printf("morse code string: %s\n",string4);
    free(string1);
    return;
}

char *morse2english(char *morsecode)
{
    int j=0;
    int a=0;
    char *azarray=(char*)malloc(26);
    strcpy(azarray, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    char *morsearray=(char*)malloc(104*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(morsearray, ".-  -...-.-.-.. .   ..-.--. ......  .----.- .-..--  -.  --- .--.--.-.-. ... -   ..- ...-.-- -..--.----..");
        for (int i = 0; i < 104; ++i )
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    if((morsecode[j++] == morsearray[i++]))
    a =((morsearray[i-4])/4);
    char *ch =(char*)malloc(1*sizeof(char));
    ch=azarray+a;
    return ch;
}
```

the function keyread is supposed to split the morse string into 4 chars 
and pass that to the `morse2english` function which is supposed to find the alphabetical representation of the morse code 
and return it to the keyread function and add it to `string4`

Comment: So what's your actual question?

Comment: Your first while loop looks to me like it will never exit? (and should probably be `*string1`). `keyread1()` also leaks like a sieve.

Comment: I think that your design is wrong and it imposes an artificial requirement that Morse be presented in 4-symbol groups including the non-symbol 'space'.  I'd implement a representation of the morse code as a binary tree labelling the branches at each level either `.` or `-`.  Then the algorithm for reading Morse and writing English letters is: start at the root of the tree, get the next code symbol, follow the correct branch, continue until you get a leaf (which will therefore correspond to a letter), go back to the root. This way you can handle a continuous stream of Morse.

Comment: The coding problem is that you fail to allocate space for null terminators, that you rarely free any data that you allocate, that you use return by pointer when a return by value is more appropriate, and finally that you assign pointer that you have just allocated, making the allocated memory inaccessible. A logical problem is that you always check all four spots of the morse code, even though your table has a space in the corresponding place.

Answer (score 0):

I was putting the problems in a comment, but there are just too many! You really need to go back and study some more - especially about dynamic memory allocation!

in keyread1:

- All the strcpy stuff with malloced buffers is not necessary. eg: you malloc 20 bytes for string3 but before you use it you say string3=..., so it's an instant leak!
- while(string1 != '\0') is not comparing apples to apples: string 1 is a pointer, \0 is a character. You probable mean *string1, but then you never modify string1, so the loop wont end.
- You never modify a in the loop, so you aren't appending to the string4
- The result of morse2english is dynamically allocated but you never free it.

in morse2english:

- you malloc an array of 26, (which doesn't allow a null terminator so you have a buffer overrun)
- you never free azarray - why malloc in the first place, you don't modify it, so a string literal would work.
- Ditto for morsearray (I didn't count it, but you don't change it, so no need to malloc and strcpy)
- The for loop appears to be gibberish: for each individual char in all the morse code, look at the input (and modify the indexes used by the for loops)

Comment: Just to add to that. Don't typecast the return from `malloc()` and don't waste time doung `*sizeof(char)` in your call to malloc, `sizeof(char)` is 1